# VLC player not playing recorded video

Tags: vlc-media-player

I am able to open an mp4 file and play it on Windows media player but not on VLC. It just shows the first frame and then it freezes. Why is this?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of VLC?

Comment: @Moab: Yes, I even reinstalled it.

Comment: What does `Tools -> Codec Information` say?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your file is DRM protected or the codec isn't installed for VLC. Try reinstalling VLC or installing additional codecs

Edit: try resetting your preferences in VLC, you might have inadvertently messed up something.

Comment: VLC usues its own set of codecs.

Comment: I do believe that @GrantorShadow is on to something here even if he is wrong about the solution.. sure, VLC has it's own codecs.. but no.. apparently not this one.